Running bash scripts against a K8S Manifest file which uses Helm templating
I want to run a kubesec scan against some of my K8S manifest files, the issue is that I'm using Helm templating in my files and when I try to execute a simple bash script I get errors like these
Performing kubesec scan - Static security analysis for Kubernetes manifests
Scan result: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.backendDeploymentName":interface {}(nil)}

My bash script looks like this to run a scan against the manifest files and check the resulting scores.
#!/bin/bash

scan_result=$(curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"backend_manifest_file" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan)
scan_message=$(curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"backend_manifest_file" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan | jq .[0].message -r )
scan_score=$(curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"backend_manifest_file" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan | jq .[0].score )

echo "Performing kubesec scan - Static security analysis for Kubernetes manifests"
echo "Scan result: $scan_result"
echo "Scan message: $scan_message"
echo "Scan score: $scan_score"

if [[ "${scan_score}" -ge 5 ]]; then
    echo "Score is $scan_score"
    echo "Kubesec Scan $scan_message"
else
    echo "Score is $scan_score, which is less than or equal to 5."
    echo "Scanning Kubernetes Resource has Failed"
    exit 1;
fi;

My manifest files use Helm templating where I reference variables in my values.yaml file.
What's a solution for this?
I could have a separate version of the manifest file that does not make use of Helm and run it against that, but I don't really want to have that for each manifest file.

As an aside, why don't you get scan_message and scan_score off of scan_result instead of curling over and over again?

@pmf Didnt even notice that lol, I got the script from somewhere else and just made minor changes, Thank you.

You can't run any sort of validation against the Helm templates because they are (in most cases) not syntactically valid YAML documents.
You will need to first render the templates to YAML (using e.g. the helm template command) and then validate the rendered version.
E.g.:
tmpfile=$(mktemp manifestXXXXXX.yaml)
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

helm template . > "$tmpfile"
scan_result=$(
  curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"$tmpfile" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan
)
.
.
.


Thank you! I added something like this in my script and it works.
